# How to create a cast iron texture to make it look like real cast iron cookware in Blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, 3d-view, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

[image]I created a 3D model for cast iron cookware, and now I want to apply a real cast iron cookware texture to make it look like the real thing. I don't know how to create it. Can anybody explain, please?

Comment: pls add at least an image how it should look like. thx.

Comment: Hello, Dharmik .. welcome..  even though cast-iron cookware has a fairly uniform appearance, it's still good practice to provide a visual reference. (Completely BTW,  you would quickly discover _why_ in a professional environment  :D )